# How to use _.pull() with regular expressions in Lodash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I want to remove elements from an array when they match a certain regular expression.

[Here is the Lodash documentation on the `pull()` method.](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#pull)

I want a result similar to this.

```
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'];
 
_.pull(array, 'b', 'c',);
console.log(array); // [ 'a', 'a', ]
```

Only, I want to use regex instead of strings. But this does not achieve that result.

```
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'];
const re = /(b|c)/gm
 
_.pull(array, re,);
console.log(array); // ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You only want to do it using lodash? Seems like it could be done fairly simply using vanilla JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_.pull()` method doesn't accept a predicate, use [`_.remove()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#remove):

> Removes all elements from array that predicate returns truthy for

```js
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'];
const re = /b|c/
 
_.remove(array, c => re.test(c));

console.log(array); // ["a", "a"]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in a vanilla JS solution, see below for using RegExp test!

```js
let array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'];
const re = /(b|c)/
 
array = array.filter(el => !re.test(el));
console.log(array);
```